# AWS Cloudfront - Cache Behaviour - Path Pattern format

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

The documentation for the Path Pattern property is not exactly exhaustive.

> The pattern to which this cache behavior applies. For example, you can specify images/*.jpg

Now, i understand the path pattern could be things like `images/*` and other simple variations but, can it be something like `/path/*/latest/`?

I can save that pattern but it doesn't seem to work as expected. It looks like Cloufront ignores everything after the `*` and caches everything below `path/*`, regardless of the fact that `/path/*/latest` is the top behaviour (0 order) with a TTL of zero.

To further clarify, i have a `/path/*` that i want to be served (and cached) by cloudfront, with the exception of one particular subpath, say `path/*/latest` that can be served by Cloudfront, but shouldn't be cached (hence i gave it a TTL of zero).

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be with the ordering of the behaviours. Does `path/*/latest` occur before `/path/*`? Cache behaviors are processed in the order in which they're listed in the CloudFront console

Comment: yep, as i said path/*/latest is the top (first, zero order) behaviour. I suspect the problem is due to the caching of 404 errors. Haven't confirmed it yet

Comment: CloudFront shouldn't cache 404s for any longer than 5 mins (assuming you haven't changed the default error caching duration)